# Pointers getting allocated the same memory space

Tags: c++

I am writing a program in C++ that uses the following function which has two character pointers (of course, acting as strings) as its formal arguments :

```
void takeword (char *dstr, const char *from)                                                             
{
int i=0, j=0;

printf ("\n %s", dstr);
getch();
exit(0);

while (!isalpha(from[i]))                   //positioning to the first letter in te line
    i++;

do
{
    dstr[j]=from[i];
    j++;
    i++;
}while (isalpha(from[i]));

dstr[j]='\0';                   //terminating the word with a null character
};
```

My problem is that the two strings dstr and from are being allocated the same memory space.
As a result, the changes being made in dstr are being reflected in from which I don't want.

So, what to do to ensure that they are allocated different memory locations ?

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: "what to do to ensure that they are allocated different memory locations" - You don't pass in pointers to the same memory...

Comment: Did you do something like `from = dstr` before you call the function?

Comment: Obviously enough if you don't want that to happen then create a distinct buffer to `dstr`. If you are giving `dstr` and `from` as same pointer it will ruin the original variable, naturally.

Answer (score 0):

The only case that the code you've given does not handle in a satisfactory way is the case that `dstr > from && dstr < from + strlen(from)`.

To fix this, you have three options:

1. You write your function in a way that ensures correct operation independent of whether the two strings overlap or not. This is likely to involve a temporary buffer.
2. You document in the function declaration that the function won't handle overlapping buffers correctly, and make sure that the calling code does not violate this restriction. In this case you might consider adding the `restrict` keyword to the function arguments to document this assumption both to the programmer and the compiler (which will be able to do additional optimizations. It would also be a good idea to insert an `assert()` that checks for the overlapping condition.
3. You go in the opposite direction and change the function signature to `void takeword (char *string)` and document that it will move the first word to the start of the string and add a terminating null character.

It is up to you to decide which solution you prefer in your situation, it all depends on the use case at hand.